# Magento 2 | Change dropdown values on bundle products to custom attribute

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

We have bundle products with dropdown options. Per default dropdown options of a bundle product contain „product name“ and „price“. For example:

Value 1 = „Black Shirt Size M +$9.95“
Value 2 = „Black Shirt Size L +$9.95“

What I am trying to achieve:
Dropdown options shall contain neither product name nor price, but the product attribute „size“ of each product. Example: bundle product has a dropdown option whereas this option contains various sizes of the same shirt:

Value 1 = „Size M“
Value 2 = „Size L“

**What I did:**
I rewrote the following block:
\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option.php

I changed „getSelectionTitlePrice“ function in order to get the size attribute and remove product name and price.

$priceTitle = $this->escapeHtml($selection->getSize());

**Result:**
In the source code the result is as expected: dropdown values consist of the size attribute of each product only.

**Problem:**
Frontend still shows „product name“ + „price“. I assume this is being caused by some script overwriting the output. Unfortunately, i am not familiar with JS / Knockout.

Could anybody give me a hint how to suppress the dropdown values being overwritten? Hope this makes sense.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js file which is updating the title is

```
vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/web/js/price-bundle.js
```

Function: `_applyOptionNodeFix`

This function is updating dropdown options with js.

You can override this to theme files:

```
app/design/theme/package/Magento_Bundle/web/js/price-bundle.js
```

and comment the last line in the function `$option.html(template(toTemplate));` to `//$option.html(template(toTemplate));`

For additional changes you can play around in the file/function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Shivanand - very appreciated!

Comment: Thank for the path to JS file, very useful @Shivanand. I just wanted to add that if you need the function that exposes the data for the JS you can find that at "vendor/magento/module-bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php", Function "getSelectionItemData"