# Magento 2 | Configurable Products: Change default value / title of (size) dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, magento2

Magento CE 2.4.6.
Configurable Products.

Option dropdowns of configurable products have the following default value:

> Choose an Option...

I want to change this to the title of the attribute. I therefore copied the following template to my custom theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options.phtml
```

And did the following changes:

```
<option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Choose an Option...')) ?></option>
```

To:

```
<option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></option>
```

This basically works. However, once the page has been loaded the default value is being updated / overwritten by some JS-File. I could not figure out which file is responsible for this. I was facing the same problem with dropdowns on BUNDLE pages and got help in this ticket:

[Question 58558714](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558714/magento-2-change-dropdown-values-on-bundle-products-to-custom-attribute)

Do you have an idea which JS file is responsible for the overwrite?

Thank you!
Alex